# Accessing web server internally via external address (via domain name)

Tags: networking, smoothwall

I have a smoothwall set up in my home network along with a little web server (seperate machines).

A domain name is set up for the external address of the network. 
Port 80 is forwarded to the server.

- Accessing the web server externally (if anyone outside the network tries to access it) **works**.
- Accessing the web server internally via its internal IP **works**.
- Accessing the web server internally via the domain name **does *not* work**.

I believe this has something to do with smoothwalls anti-spoofing rules.

**How would I go about to make the domain name work for internal connections?**

The server is running debian, I am running Windows 7 64bit and my roommate is running mac OSX.

Comment: Home-network stuff is off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what OS you're using, but unless you can do a [DNS rewrite](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/products_configuration_example09186a00807968d1.shtml) (like you can on Cisco firewalls), the quickest way is to add an entry in your hosts file.

**Updated to add:**

An internal DNS server seems to be the only other option you're going to have, if you don't want to edit hosts files and you can't do a DNS rewrite on your smoothwall box.

Comment: Updated the question, updating the host file isn't really a long term solution since I tend to have a bunch of domain names being added and removed.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at

http://community.smoothwall.org/forum/

I am Sure that the people can help you there.

Bugan

Answer (score 1):

If you are just NATing only on port 80, it is pretty simple to get this done. Try adding a "Static DNS" to local web server on Smoothwall under Services tab, and your public domain name as hostname., i.e "mydomain.com". This would mostly solve your issue

If this is not a solution to your problem. Let me know your exact setting with some sample IP addresses and port numbers

Answer (score 0):

You are having a split-dns issue.  Your home machine is getting a DNS response which is pointing your home machine to the external address (like 208.5.x.x).  Your home machine is trying to connect via the external address.  You are correct in that your firewall would block that.

If your home router is something like dd-wrt and runs a dns server (or you are running your own DNS server), you can update the A records on there to point to your interal IP address (192.168.x.x or something like that).

If you don't have that, you'll need to edit the hosts files on your local machines to point to the internal address.

On linux the /etc/hosts file is where you need to go.
On windows, it's windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Edit those with "192.168.1.100 www.myserver.com" (using the provided examples in the files) and you'll be good to go and be able to reach it by the name you like.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the server runs Debian and there is a bunch of domain names to be managed, I would suggest setting up DNS on the server (with recursive lookups through the DNS server provided by your ISP), and configuring the DHCP on the router to use this DNS server (otherwise your other computers on your home network will never ask that shiny new DNS server for answers and you're still stuck).

Alternatively you could also set up DHCP on the debian server and disable the DHCP on your router (gives you more flexibility, but possibly also a steeper learning curve).

In any case, @Matt is correct in that you need to set up internal name resolution for these domains, pointing at the internal IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link if you're using DD-WRT. Specifically item two on DNSMasq.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_-_DNS_for_your_local_network_-_HOWTO